# Finding the record that would come before and after a given number

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table with a application number, sequence and date. When a new sequence number for an application is to be added, I need to check for the date of the previous sequence and the date for the sequence that would come after (if it exists).

Table example:

```
APPNO   SEQUENCE   DATE
17638       1      08/10/2019
17638       2      08/12/2019
17638       4      08/20/2019
```

If I want to add the same application with sequence=3, I would have to check for the date of the previous sequence and the one after. If I want to add the same application with sequence=5, I would only check for the date of the last sequence added.

Using a record set how can I accomplish this? How can I loop through the record set and get the desired information in Access VBA?

I have created a record set and set up the loop, but I don't know where to go from here. I am new to Access.

Started with

```
strSql = "SELECT ST_APPNO_TX, ST_SEQUENCE_TXT, ST_DATE_DT FROM SUBMISSIONS_TBL where ST_APPNO_TXT= = '" & appno & "' ORDER ST_SEQUENCE_TXT;"
maxVal = DLookup("[MaxVal]", "[MaxSequence_qry]", "[ST_APPNO_TXT]=" & appno)

Set cnnLocalConnection = CurrentProject.AccessConnection
        Set rstSequence = New ADODB.Recordset

        rstSequence.Open strSql, cnnLocalConnection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
        preSeq = ""
        For N = 1 To rstSequence.RecordCount
```

I would like to get the value for the previous sequence and the sequence after (if it exists)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to obtain the information you require - you could obtain the preceding the succeeding sequence records for a given application & sequence using the following SQL queries:

**Preceding Sequence record:**

```
select top 1 t.* 
from submissions_tbl t
where 
    t.st_appno_txt = [YourAppNo] and 
    t.st_sequence_txt < [YourSequenceNo] 
order by 
    t.st_sequence_txt desc
```

**Succeeding Sequence record:**

```
select top 1 t.* 
from submissions_tbl t
where 
    t.st_appno_txt = [YourAppNo] and 
    t.st_sequence_txt > [YourSequenceNo] 
order by 
    t.st_sequence_txt
```

Alternatively, you could obtain the preceding or succeeding Sequence number using the `DMax` or `DMin` functions respectively:

**Preceding Sequence Number:**

```
DMax("st_sequence_txt", "submissions_tbl", "st_appno_txt = '17638' and st_sequence_txt < '3'")
```

**Succeeding Sequence Number:**

```
DMin("st_sequence_txt", "submissions_tbl", "st_appno_txt = '17638' and st_sequence_txt > '3'")
```